# Use par inside another par

Tags: r, plot, figure

I do not sure if this even possible but I am attaching a figure I like to do it in R instead of using paint. [image: Example figure]

```
x=rnorm(10,4,5)
y=rnorm(10,4,5)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(x,y)

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(x,y)
plot(x,y)
plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I assume you are looking for a base-like way of doing this, but you can also used `ggplot`. Here are both solutions.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
x=rnorm(10,4,5)
y=rnorm(10,4,5)

m <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,3,4),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
layout(m)

plot(x,y)
plot(x,y)
plot(x,y)
plot(x,y)
```

```
p1 = ggplot(data.frame(x=x, y=y), aes(x, y))+geom_point()
grid.arrange(p1, p1, p1, p1, layout_matrix = m)
```

Comment: That works! Thanks! is there a way to give the bottom 3 one big title or just use the title on the middle one?

Comment: One way is to first combine the bottom 3 ggplots and the title using `grid.arrange`. Then, you can combine the first plot with the plot resulting from the combined plots:


`p1 = ggplot(data.frame(x=x, y=y), aes(x, y))+geom_point();
p2 = grid.arrange(p1, p1, p1, nrow=1, top= textGrob(label='big tile', gp = gpar(fontsize = 20)));
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=1)`